# Windows 2008 NPS server unable to authenticate Ubuntu client on wireless

Tags: peap

I have Windows clients able to authenticate (EAP-PEAP MSCHAPV2) configured to authenticate with Windows 2008 server with no issues, however i am not using any Server certificate for outer-EAP (Neither Third party cert nor Internal Cert) by un-checking the option "Validate server cert".

But have issue with Ubuntu client machines which says CA cert unknown in the wireshark captures though the CA cert option under WiFi-settings is set to "None".

Would it atleast require Self-signed cert for the Ubuntu client to authenticate or it should work without validating the cert. I am also not sure, how is the client seeing any cert when there is none to be verified by it.

Also are there any websites/CA authorities which provide Public cert for testing to come out of this issue ?

Any feedback is appreciable.